# izpack does not create shortcut on Windows 8 x64

Tags: izpack

I have IzPack installation for jar executable. 
ShortcutPanel is declared, shortcutSpec.xml is picked up well and install.xml contains

```
<natives>
    <native type="izpack" name="ShellLink.dll"/>
    <native type="izpack" name="ShellLink_x64.dll"/>
</natives>
```

In resulting installer jar, I see both above mentioned DLLs under the following path: 
com\izforge\izpack\bin\native\izpack\

Installation goes through "Create shortcut" panel but no shortcuts created in  programs or desktop, although "shortcut" tag has:

```
programGroup="true"
desktop="true"
applications="true"
startMenu="false"
startup="false"
```

When turned DEBUG on for installation, I see the following:

```
Failed to load library: ShellLink: no ShellLink in java.library.path java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no ShellLink in java.library.path
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
        at com.izforge.izpack.util.Librarian.loadSystemLibrary(Librarian.java:35 8)
        at com.izforge.izpack.util.Librarian.loadArchSpecificLibrary(Librarian.j ava:236)
        at com.izforge.izpack.util.Librarian.loadLibrary(Librarian.java:122)
        at com.izforge.izpack.util.os.ShellLink.initialize(ShellLink.java:529)
        at com.izforge.izpack.util.os.ShellLink.<init>(ShellLink.java:397)
        at com.izforge.izpack.util.os.Win_Shortcut.initialize(Win_Shortcut.java: 85)
        at com.izforge.izpack.panels.shortcut.ShortcutPanelLogic.<init>(Shortcut PanelLogic.java:187)
        at com.izforge.izpack.panels.shortcut.ShortcutPanel.<init>(ShortcutPanel .java:194)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)

        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Sou rce)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector.newInstance(AbstractInje ctor.java:145)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$1.run(ConstructorInje ctor.java:342)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDepende ncyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:270)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector.getComponentInstance( ConstructorInjector.java:364)
        at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.getComponentInstance(Abs tractBehavior.java:64)
        at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.getComponentInstance(Stored.java:9 1)
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContain er.java:699)
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContai ner.java:647)
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContai ner.java:678)
        at com.izforge.izpack.core.container.AbstractContainer.getComponent(Abst ractContainer.java:131)
        at com.izforge.izpack.core.factory.DefaultObjectFactory.create(DefaultOb jectFactory.java:74)
        at com.izforge.izpack.core.factory.DefaultObjectFactory.create(DefaultOb jectFactory.java:102)
        at com.izforge.izpack.installer.panel.AbstractPanelView.createView(Abstr actPanelView.java:372)
        at com.izforge.izpack.installer.panel.AbstractPanelView.getView(Abstract PanelView.java:185)
        at com.izforge.izpack.installer.gui.IzPanels.initialise(IzPanels.java:80 )
        at com.izforge.izpack.installer.gui.InstallerFrame.buildGUI(InstallerFra me.java:374)
        at com.izforge.izpack.installer.gui.InstallerController$1.run(InstallerC ontroller.java:35)
        at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionP rivilege(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)

Failed to load library: C:\Users\krok\AppData\Local\Temp\ShellLink88513690863102
40915.dll: C:\Users\krok\AppData\Local\Temp\ShellLink8851369086310240915.dll: Ca n't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Users\krok\AppData\Local\Temp\ShellLink885136
9086310240915.dll: Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform
        at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.System.load(Unknown Source)
        at com.izforge.izpack.util.Librarian.load(Librarian.java:381)
        at com.izforge.izpack.util.Librarian.loadJarLibrary(Librarian.java:333)
        at com.izforge.izpack.util.Librarian.loadFromClassPath(Librarian.java:29 3)
        at com.izforge.izpack.util.Librarian.loadArchSpecificLibrary(Librarian.j ava:236)
        at com.izforge.izpack.util.Librarian.loadLibrary(Librarian.java:122)
        at com.izforge.izpack.util.os.ShellLink.initialize(ShellLink.java:529)
        at com.izforge.izpack.util.os.ShellLink.<init>(ShellLink.java:397)
        at com.izforge.izpack.util.os.Win_Shortcut.initialize(Win_Shortcut.java: 85)
        at com.izforge.izpack.panels.shortcut.ShortcutPanelLogic.<init>(Shortcut PanelLogic.java:187)
        at com.izforge.izpack.panels.shortcut.ShortcutPanel.<init>(ShortcutPanel .java:194)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)

        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Sou rce)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector.newInstance(AbstractInje ctor.java:145)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$1.run(ConstructorInje ctor.java:342)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDepende ncyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:270)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector.getComponentInstance( ConstructorInjector.java:364)
        at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.getComponentInstance(Abs tractBehavior.java:64)
        at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.getComponentInstance(Stored.java:9 1)
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContain er.java:699)
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContai ner.java:647)
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContai ner.java:678)
        at com.izforge.izpack.core.container.AbstractContainer.getComponent(Abst ractContainer.java:131)
        at com.izforge.izpack.core.factory.DefaultObjectFactory.create(DefaultOb jectFactory.java:74)
        at com.izforge.izpack.core.factory.DefaultObjectFactory.create(DefaultOb jectFactory.java:102)
        at com.izforge.izpack.installer.panel.AbstractPanelView.createView(Abstr actPanelView.java:372)
        at com.izforge.izpack.installer.panel.AbstractPanelView.getView(Abstract PanelView.java:185)
        at com.izforge.izpack.installer.gui.IzPanels.initialise(IzPanels.java:80 )
        at com.izforge.izpack.installer.gui.InstallerFrame.buildGUI(InstallerFra me.java:374)
        at com.izforge.izpack.installer.gui.InstallerController$1.run(InstallerC ontroller.java:35)
        at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionP rivilege(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I am not sure whether 32-bit DLL error it is critical, because installation must use 64-bit one, which is also provided. But there are no traces of using ShellLink_x64.dll in log at all. 
Also the script contains

```
<run-privileged/>
```

so it works under admin rights. 
Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

I've downgraded from IzPack 5.1.2 to 5.0.6 and it worked, with the same scripts. 
Noticed that com\izforge\izpack\bin\native\ in resulting JAR now contains more folders and DLLs, not only ShellLink.dll and ShellLink_x64.dll .